# How to summarize data from one second in Graphite?

Tags: python, linux, frequency, graphite

I am new to Graphite. I just wrote a Python script that generates data within graphite, however I am sending in the value of 1 for each datapoint, and there are multiple datapoints for each second. What is the easiest way to turn the graph, which right now is just a straight line, into a frequency graph?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the Graphite Webapp:

For example, if you series name is testing.hits and you are looking at a graph of it (the horizontal line), then click Graph Data -> select your series -> Apply Function -> Transform -> Summarize and choose the time duration.

```
summarize(testing.hits, "1min")
```

Also check out the [docs](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html)